# Not repeating the function once waypoint reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

Here is the JS for the waypoint call and graph bar function. It repeats every time the waypoint is reached and I would like it to recognise that the waypoint has been reached once already ad not to repeat function. Thanks for your help. :)

```
$.getScript('http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.min.js', function() {

    $('#jack_bellamy').waypoint(function() {
        setTimeout(function start (){

      $('.bar').each(function(i)
      {  
        var $bar = $(this);
        $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
        setTimeout(function(){
          $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));     
        }, i*100);
      });

    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) +'%');
            }
        });
    });

    }, 500)

    });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want a waypoint to keep triggering you can [destroy](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/destroy) it. To ensure it only runs once, you can destroy it at the end of your handler. The `this` keyword refers to the waypoint instance you can call destroy on within the handler.

```
$('#jack_bellamy').waypoint(function() {
  // all that animation stuff you mentioned
  this.destroy();
});
```